# How to allow users add dynamic custom fields on a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to have a profile page where a user can add certain fields over and over on a custom fields form.

The fields will be represented in the UI like:

```
Input Field (Name)    |    Input Field (Number)             + (Add new)
```

So when the user clicks on Add new, the fields above are duplicated like below:

```
Input Field (Name)    |    Input Field (Number) 
Input Field (Name)    |    Input Field (Number)
```

I read that custom Fields is what I need and tried putting the block of code below in my themes functions.php file:

```
// handle custom meta boxes for the user progile page
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'register_new_user_field');
function register_new_user_field(){
  global $post;
  if(!empty($post))
  {
    $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

    if($pageTemplate == 'page-templates/template-dashboard.php' ){
      add_meta_box(
            'custom-user-post-id',
            'Label',
            'customer_submit_callback',
            'page',
        'normal',
        'high'
        );
    }
  }
}

function customer_submit_callback(){
    // display output to user
        echo '<label for="custom-user-post-id"><p>Custom Title</p></label>';
    echo '<input name="custom-user-post-id" id="custom-user-post-id" cols="62" rows="5" ></input>';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
}

function wpdocs_save_meta_box($post_id){
    // Save logic
    // // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
  }
  if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( isset( $_POST['custom-user-post-id'] ) )
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom-user-post-id', $_POST['custom-user-post-id'] );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpdocs_save_meta_box' );
```

However, those fields aren't present when i go to the user profile page. any helps would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `add_meta_boxes` is not a user-related hook.  It puts metaboxes on the edit post / page screen.  You are looking for [edit_user_profile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile).

Answer (score 0):

So what you're looking to do is add sections on a page that the user can edit at their leisure.

- Step 1. Download Advanced Custom Fields
- Step 2. Create A Field Group
- Step 3. Click Add Field
- Step 4. Set the field label to: Custom Post ID
- Step 5. Set the field name to custom_post_id
- Step 6. Select the type Text
- Step 7. Scroll down to Options
- Step 8. Select "Side" From the positions drop down
- Step 9. Click Save/Publish/Update

**To restrict where the meta box appears, in the location field select:**

**Page Template > Is Equal To > Your Template**

Now the box will appear with all the other metaboxes on all pages.

In order to make the ID actually useful I am assuming you will be echoing it out somewhere so here is how you would do that:

```
<?php the_field('custom_post_id');?>
```

An example of an actual case of using it:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-<?php the_field('custom_post_id');?>">
```

If the user entered "1" in the field in the admin area it would display this:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-1">
```